# .git/FETCH_HEAD is written with blank content

Tags: git

For some reason, .git/FETCH_HEAD file is always blank.

```
$ uname -v   
Darwin Kernel Version 22.1.0: Sun Oct  9 20:14:54 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8792.41.9~2/RELEASE_X86_64
$ git --version
git version 2.37.1 (Apple Git-137.1)
$ git config --list
credential.helper=osxkeychain
init.defaultbranch=main
include.path=~/common/.gitconfig
core.excludesfile=/Users/khoan/.gitignore_global
user.name=Khoa Nguyen
user.email=khoa@nguyen.com
push.default=current
includeif.gitdir:~/srv/project/.path=~/srv/project/.gitconfig
user.email=khoa.nguyen@project.com
core.sshcommand=ssh -i ~/.ssh/project-id_ed25519
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:khoan/project.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/origin/main
$ git fetch origin feature-branch
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/khoan/.ssh/project-id_ed25519': 
remote: Enumerating objects: 7, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 7 (delta 4), reused 5 (delta 4), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), 2.90 KiB | 247.00 KiB/s, done.
From github.com:khoan/project
 * branch                    feature-branch -> FETCH_HEAD
$ wc .git/FETCH_HEAD
     0       0       0 .git/FETCH_HEAD
```

Ideas on possible cause and fix? Thanks.

Comment: Does `git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir` print the path to the current directory's .git?

Comment: ```$ git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir => /Users/khoan/srv/project/main/.git```

Answer (score 0):

The only instance I know of where `FETCH_HEAD` would not be written is by using the `git fetch --no-write-fetch-head`, which should not be the case here.

So try and check if the issue persists in a new clone, separate folder, when fetching in said new clone. Just to rule out a process which might keep an handle on that file preventing its update.

The [OP Khoa Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033197/khoa-nguyen) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75078775/git-fetch-head-is-written-with-blank-content/75092783?noredirect=1#comment132534117_75092783):

> stat `.git/FETCH_HEAD` reveals that the file is modified after `git fetch origin main`. T

Comment: Looks like a comment rather than an real answer?

Comment: @knittl I will flesh it out once the OP has given feedback.

Comment: worth a shot, but no love: `git clone git@github.com:khoan/project.git project-0`, `cd project-0`, `git fetch origin main`, `wc .git/FETCH_HEAD # =>        0       0       0 .git/FETCH_HEAD`. Is there some global config for `--no-write-fetch-head` that I can check? Thanks.

Comment: @KhoaNguyen As far as I know, there is no matching configuration for that fetch option.

Comment: `stat .git/FETCH_HEAD` reveals that the file is modified after `git fetch origin main`. Thanks.

Comment: @KhoaNguyen Good catch. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.